# Breaking down complex XML layouts using the same data-binding context

Tags: android, xml, data-binding

## Context

XML layouts in Android can get complicated. Hence, it is a good practice to break them down into conceptually independent modules. Consider the following example:

Main layout:

```
<layout>
   <data>
       <variable name="someVar" type="some.custom.Type"/>
   </data>

   <SomeLayout 
       ...
       android:someAttribute="@{someVar.someProperty}" />

   <include layout="@layout/some_other_layout />
</layout>
```

and `some_other_layout.xml`:

```
<SomeOtherLayout 
       ...
       android:someOtherAttribute="@{someVar.someOtherProperty}" />
```

## Problem

Is it possible to use the same data-binding context (whatever is inside `<data>`) in two separated layouts (like in the given example)?

Doing this naively results in `java.lang.IllegalStateException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [**Data Binding Library** documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html):

> Variables may be passed into an included layout's binding from the containing layout by using the application namespace and the variable name in an attribute:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>         xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
>     <data>
>         <variable name="user" type="com.example.User"/>
>     </data>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:orientation="vertical"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent">
>         <include layout="@layout/name"
>             bind:user="@{user}"/>
>         <include layout="@layout/contact"
>             bind:user="@{user}"/>
>     </LinearLayout>
> </layout>
> ```